# How payloads provide backdoors when the victims are out of local network

Tags: metasploit, backdoor, trojan

I am a newbie in cyber security and trying to learn how payloads provide backdoors when the victims are out of the local network.

I know that metasploit is a good tool for making payloads, and using some other tools we can also turn our payloads to trojans. Moreover, using msfconsole, we can gain a shell from a box in our local network if the victim clicks on our trap. Up to this point, I do not have questions.

However, hackers do not always use these trojans or payloads when they are in the same local network. They can even control our computers from other countries.

When we construct our payloads, we write our local IP addresses. **However if the victims are out of our local network, how do hackers gain the backdoors using payloads or trojans?**

Comment: By not putting your local, private, non-Internet-routable IP address as the IP the payload needs to connect to ... You supply an IP the target *can* connect to. The rest is a network routing problem to solve.

Comment: I think you are missing that two computers can connect even if they are not in the same local network. Any website you visit is very likely not in the local network and you can still connect to it. Similar to a public web server an attacker can also be on a publicly reachable IP address and thus be accessible from the victim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general:

- if the victim machine is reachable from the attacker's machine, then the attacker can connect to it directly (for the sake of brevity, let's ignore how firewalls complicate things)
- if the victim machine is not reachable from the attacker (e.g. is on a different LAN than the attacker's and has a private IP), then the attacker has to make *the victim connect to the attacker's machine*, by using a [reverse connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_connection). This implies that *the attacker's machine needs to be reachable* from the victim (e.g. have a public IP or be reachable through [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding))

For example, in the case where the attacker's and the victim's machines are on different LANs that use private IPs, like this:

```
attacker (private IP) --> attacker's router (public IP)
                             |
                            \|/
                        [internet]
                             |
                             |
                              --> router (public IP) --> victim (private IP)
```

then you need to make the attacker's machine reachable from the victim's machine, so that you connect to the victim through a reverse connection. You can do it by configuring the attacker's router to forward one of its ports to a port on the attacker's machine, where a [listener](https://docs.rapid7.com/metasploit/listeners/) is accepting connections; you, then, insert into the payload *the attacker's router IP* and the *forwarded port*.

Another approach would be that the attacker connects to another (third) machine, which is publicly reachable, and attack the victim from that box.

Comment: thanks for clear explanation . I wonder something else such that as far as i know msfvenom do not have property for public IP , do you know any tool for that ?

Comment: @SalmonFish you'll have to set the LHOST and LPORT accordingly

Comment: yes , iknow it , but in that case i will have to set both public ip and private ip , because there are many other devices in my router. However , as far as i know msfvenom allows only for one ip

Comment: @Spyros The terminology you're using is slightly wrong. The term "private IP" usually refers to a reserved IP address for use in a local network. You probably mean a system behind a NAT without any form of port forwarding set up.

Comment: @forest I've amended the answer to address your comment

Comment: @SalmonFish why do you need to set multiple IPs? As I guessed, this is a pure routing and networking question rather than a security question. You need to figure out your routing.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot reach the victim via their local network, don't use the local network. The great thing about IP is that forwarding decisions can be made *between* two unrelated networks. Each router only needs to have a proper routing table (i.e. it only needs to know about itself and the peers that it is connected to directly over the link-layer) to make decisions. As long as your victim is reachable, you can connect to them, or they can connect to you (assuming no firewall policies get in the way).

You can either use a reverse shell where you provide the IP of a computer that the victim will attempt to connect to, or a regular shell where you need to know the victim's IP and can connect *to* them. Both of these can be done over the wider Internet, crossing many different networks.